# I want these images to be vertically aligned how do i accomplish this?

Tags: html, css

I want to align images vertically and I am having trouble.
http://jsfiddle.net/k9t5k7v0/1/

Below is my code allowing for a responsive list. But, how can I get all the logos that are rectangular to be vertically aligned?

```css
.container {
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
.container:before,
.container:after {
  display: table;
  content: "";
}
.container:after {
  clear: both;
}
.container ul {
  padding: 10px;
}
#aff_rating {
  list-style-type: none;
}
#aff_rating li {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 6px;
  width: 100px;
}
#aff_rating li img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  #aff_rating li {
    width: 30px;
  }
}
.crop {
  height: 100px;
  width: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.crop img {
  height: auto;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul id="aff_rating" style="list-style-type: none;">
    <li class="crop">
      <img src="http://www.opsplus.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/pacific-life-lgo.jpg" alt="pacific-life-lgo" width="492" height="246" class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-2140" />
    </li>
    <li class="crop">
      <img src="http://www.opsplus.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/Southwest-Securities-RGB.jpg" alt="Southwest Securities RGB" width="590" height="111" class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-2137" />
    </li>
    <li class="crop">
      <img src="http://www.opsplus.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/Sterne_Agee.gif" alt="Sterne_Agee" width="215" height="38" class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-2138" />
    </li>
    <li class="crop">
      <img src="http://www.opsplus.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/Wedbush.Logo_.png" alt="Wedbush.Logo" width="224" height="38" class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-2139" />
    </li>
    <li class="crop">
      <img src="http://www.opsplus.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/schwab.jpg" alt="CSchwab_logo_core_blue_DIGITAL" width="1050" height="1050" class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-2136" />
    </li>
    <li class="crop">
      <img src="http://www.opsplus.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/prudential-logo.png" alt="prudential-logo" width="400" height="400" class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-2134" />
    </li>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/k9t5k7v0/1/

Comment: In order to vertical align, you need to be either using the display property as tables or use flexbox.

Comment: Please don't just dump your code here. To ask a good question, you must *isolate* your issue as best you can. Adding a demo with the provided button in the editor also helps.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/k9t5k7v0/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can apply `table-cell` and `vertical-align` to the middle in `li` elements:

```css
.container {
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
.container:before,
.container:after {
  display: table;
  content: "";
}
.container:after {
  clear: both;
}
.container ul {
  padding: 10px;
}
#aff_rating {
  list-style-type: none;
}
#aff_rating li {
  display: table-cell;
  margin-right: 6px;
  width: 100px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
#aff_rating li img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  #aff_rating li {
    width: 30px;
  }
}
.crop {
  height: 100px;
  width: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.crop img {
  height: auto;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul id="aff_rating" style="list-style-type: none;">
    <li class="crop">
      <img src="http://www.opsplus.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/pacific-life-lgo.jpg" alt="pacific-life-lgo" width="492" height="246" class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-2140" />
    </li>
    <li class="crop">
      <img src="http://www.opsplus.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/Southwest-Securities-RGB.jpg" alt="Southwest Securities RGB" width="590" height="111" class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-2137" />
    </li>
    <li class="crop">
      <img src="http://www.opsplus.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/Sterne_Agee.gif" alt="Sterne_Agee" width="215" height="38" class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-2138" />
    </li>
    <li class="crop">
      <img src="http://www.opsplus.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/Wedbush.Logo_.png" alt="Wedbush.Logo" width="224" height="38" class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-2139" />
    </li>
    <li class="crop">
      <img src="http://www.opsplus.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/schwab.jpg" alt="CSchwab_logo_core_blue_DIGITAL" width="1050" height="1050" class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-2136" />
    </li>
    <li class="crop">
      <img src="http://www.opsplus.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/prudential-logo.png" alt="prudential-logo" width="400" height="400" class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-2134" />
    </li>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: In your fiddle you doesn't apply my changes.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem in the beginning. but it is really very simple.
make all your relavant CSS class to `vertical-align: middle;` or `display: table-cell` or it depends

Go to following link to understand how it works

http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/v/vertical-align/

Answer (score 0):

In order for an object to be vertically aligned it needs a parent with a static height property. If the child's parent does not have a static height property, then its grandparent needs a static height property, and so on. By static height property I mean "px", not "%" or "em".

```
<div class='parent'>
    <div class='child'>Hello.</div>
</div>
```

Example 1 (position+top): http://jsfiddle.net/e1y0mtg5/1/

```
.parent {
    background: red; /* just for visual */
    position: relative; /* needed */
    height: 200px; /* needed */
}
.child {
    background:blue; /* just for visual */
    position: absolute; /* needed */
    top: 50%; /* needed */
    transform: translateY(-50%); /* needed */
}
```

Example 2 (td+valign): http://jsfiddle.net/e1y0mtg5/2/

```
.parent {
    background: red; /* just for visual */
    height: 200px; /* needed */
    display: table-cell; /* needed */
    vertical-align: middle; /* needed */
}
.child {
    background:blue; /* just for visual */
}
```

You can cheat the static height requirement if you add 100% height to the html{} and body{}, but an absolute position must always be present in the child, and this often, if not always, results in several other penalties that will make you want to rip your hair out.

```
html, body, .mydiv { height: 100%; }
```